# How to achieve conditional scenario in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to execute the below scenario in jmeter for a duration of 3600 seconds.
Scenario :
1)Login only once
2)Business Processes need to run multiple times(1 hour)
3)Logout Only once
scenario ramp up 5 sec per user and ramp-down 5-sec duration 3600second
I have to create 6 scripts in the same test plan which contains different user id and different values.

Answer (score 0):

1. `Login only once` - you don't need to do anything, or if you want full confidence use [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)
2. `Processes need to run multiple times(1 hour)` - use [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)
3. `Logout Only once` - again you don't need to do anything
4. Ramp up - can be set in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
5. Ramp down - use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) like it's decribed in [How to Ramp Down in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-ramp-down-on-jmeter)

Test plan outline:

[image]

Comment: Unique-Once: Every Vuser takes an unused (unique) data value from the text file on the first iteration and sticks to the same value for all iterations and occurrences. How to Handel this scenario in JMeter? (Thank you so much for your valuable time and for solution )

Comment: Is there any other way to handle  it because I need to  use if controller and condition like iteration == 2 or iteration % 5 == 0 it will not work under runtime controller